# graphiql send as post body instead of query string

Tags: node.js, http-post, graphql, graphql-js

On Node I am using express-graphql plugin which provides the GraphiQL UI.

GraphiQL in this implementation always sends the the query as GET querystring.

However, as I understand the GraphQL and respectively the express-graphql documentation, it should also be possible to send queries in the body of a POST request.

Is there any way to get GraphiQL (i.e. the browser IDE) to send the query in the POST body?

**Addendum Feb. 26 2017:**

I think I found what I needed to know by myself.

For whatever reason I had the query in my querystring. Like this:

`[myhostname]?query={users{[myfields]}}`

I've overlooked that.

As the express-graphql documentation points out:

> If not found in the query-string, it will look in the POST request
>   body.

This means in turn: if found in query string, it will *NOT* look in request body.

Therefore it's being treated as a GET request.

So all I needed to do, was to clean my URL from query parameters and the requests were arriving with a POST body.

That was basically all I needed to know.

So it really was a sloppy mistake which I made by not properly watching the URL i.e. not noticing there was a query in the querystring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GraphiQL` is a `React` component that is fully customizable in terms of how your data is sent to the server (`fetcher`). The `express-graphql` middleware basically pulls the transpiled GraphiQL code from a cdn and sends a static html page including it to the client: https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/blob/master/src/renderGraphiQL.js

With this knowledge you can basically do the same on a separate route, and turn off the built-in GraphiQL from `express-graphql`

Also please check the GraphiQL docs: https://github.com/graphql/graphiql!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your answer. But based on what I hope understood, let me reformulate my question:

How do I customize GraphiQL in such terms that it sends my data as POST body and not as GET query string?

Comment: Check the link in the answer. It shows you the full source how `express-graphql` does it. In fact if you check out the first example on the GraphiQL repo, it shows you exactly how you can do it as a post request: https://github.com/graphql/graphiql

Comment: @p0k8_ GraphiQL is designed exactly that way. In fact the `fetcher` that fetches your data doesn't even have to work through HTTP, you could use completely different protocols.

Comment: @p0k9_ yes it is. Neither GraphQL nor GraphiQL is restricted to parsing the query string or even HTTP. Tools built on top of it, like express-graphql might.

Comment: Glad it helped!